# Using Arrays and Validation Controls in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation-controls

The part of this assignment that I'm stuck on is this: The user must enter a state abbreviation in the "State" field (which is a standard textbox). However, I'm supposed to make sure that the the characters entered in the textbox are a valid state abbreviation. So I create an array of all 50 states, and then used a custom validator to accept the user input and compare it to all 50 state abbreviations using a for loop. However, I'm getting an error that says I haven't created a definition for an event (stateArrayCheck) even though I know I have! I have a lot more work to do on this project, so this is really frustrating being stuck on this part of the assignment. Here's my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <script>
            void stateArrayCheck (Object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
            {
                string[] states = new string[49];

                states[0] = "AL";
                states[1] = "AK";
                ...
                states[48] = "WI";
                states[49] = "WY

                for(int i=0, i <= states.count, i++)
                {
                    if(valState.text != states[i])
                    {
                        Response.Write("Please enter a valid US state.";
                    }
                }
             }
        </script>
        <style>
            #name {
                float: left;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div id ="name">
                <asp:Label id="lblFirstName" Text="First Name:" AssociatedControlID="txtFirstName" Runat="server" />
                <asp:TextBox id="txtFirstName" Runat="server" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="reqFirstName" ControlToValidate="txtFirstName" Text="(Required)" Runat="server" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <asp:Label id="lastName" text="Last Name:" runat="server" />
                <asp:TextBox id="txtLastName" Runat="server" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="reqLastName" ControlToValidate="txtLastName" Text="(Required)"Runat="server" />
                <asp:Label id="city" text="City:" runat="server" />
                <asp:TextBox id="txtCity" Runat="server" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="reqCity" ControlToValidate="txtCity" Text="(Required)" Runat="server" />
                <asp:Label id="state" text="State:" runat="server" />
                <asp:TextBox id="valState" MaxLength="2" Width="20" Runat="server" />
                <asp:CustomValidator id="reqState" ControlToValidate="valState" OnServerValidate="stateArrayCheck" Text="(Required)" Runat="server" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I know you may not be a huge fan of validators. My teacher isn't either, but they're required for this assignment. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: server side script will be identified with attribute `runat="server"` attribute. You need to add this attribute to `<script` tag that has serverside method `stateArrayCheck` also correct  `string[] states = new string[50];` and close the quotes properly for last item `states[49] = "WY";`

Comment: please do not format your code like this. And when submitting to Stack Overflow, try to be very clear and isolate the problem code instead of posting the boilerplate.

Answer (score 3):

unless this is a typo the last line is missing a quote and semi colon

```
states[49] = "WY
```

You also declare the array for 49 elements then assign 50 elements to it.

```
string[] states = new string[49];
```

You should declare for 50 and 49 is the 50th element.

```
string[] states = new string[50];
```